# Can I use libusb to get entire usb device tree?

Tags: usb, lsusb

I was wondering if it is possible to use `libusb` to get the whole USB device tree consisting of hostcontroller, root_hub, hubs and devices.
Pretty much the same thing, that `lsusb -t` does.
is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: http://libusb.org/static/api-1.0/group__dev.html#gac0fe4b65914c5ed036e6cbec61cb0b97 ?

Comment: @rajaganesh87 Thank you. I was already to list all connected devices, including the hubs. But that doesn't give me information about the tree structure( hub1->device1, hub1->hub1.2->device2 etc).